# Python, selenium Can't hook following-sibling element as xpath

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I have following html code:

[image]

I need to hook the "edit" icon for particular element which has title "test".
I tried to do

```
//*[contains(text(), 'test')]/following-sibling::div/span[@title='Edit']
```

But it doesn't work.
I can't identify this element by just title = Edit, because there are a lot of elements which will have this button edit. The only unique this is first title "test" and following sibling "Edit".

Any ideas? Would appreciate any help.Thank you

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? Please be specific. Did you just try one thing? What else have you tried? Please read [ask], especially the part about [mcve] (MCVE), and [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) This will help you debug your own programs and solve problems for yourself. If you do this and are still stuck you can come back and post your MCVE, what you tried, and the execution result including any error messages so we can better help you.

Comment: Try the following xpath //*[contains(text(), 'test')]/following-sibling::div[contains(@class,'controls')]/span[@title='Edit']

Comment: @Murthi thank you very much for providing your solution. Unfortunately I still get error - selenium can't locate this element.((

Comment: Can you post the image with all div tags expanded?

Comment: @Murthi just included the full html in a my answer. I was able to locate it with xpath //*[contains(., 'test')]/following-sibling::div/span[@title='Edit']

Answer (score 1):

You can select the div with `title`="test", then get the span with `title`="Edit" like this:

```
xpath("//div[@title='test']/following-sibling::div/span[@title='Edit']")
```

or directly select the `div` with `span` `title`='Edit':

```
xpath("//div/span[@title='Edit']")
```

Comment: I would go a little further and wrap this in a function that takes in the title and then clicks on the Edit icon corresponding to that title. That will make it very easy to reuse.

Comment: That will not work. I have more then 20 elements(and they are siblings) on the page with title ='Edit". I do have factory for all the common methods and functions. The question was just about element since I have troubles to identify it on a page and I have tried different methods.

Comment: xpath("//div[@title='test']/following-sibling::div/span[@title='Edit']") ->>> doesn't work as well. I tried that too.

Answer (score 0):

Was able to locate this element with following path:

```
//*[contains(., 'test')]/following-sibling::div/span[@title='Edit']
```

[image: image[1]]

Thank you everyone for your help.